# Error: Null is not an object

Tags: react-native

I am trying this component [react-native-calendar](https://github.com/nikches/react-native-calendar)

It always gives error `null is not an object (evaluating this.state.date)`

I tried initializing state variable named state and assign it date value but error still exists.

```
var Calendar = require('react-native-calendar-component');

export default class proj extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
date: new Date()
};
}

render() {
return (
<Calendar
date={this.state.date}
onPrevButtonPress={() => this.handlePrevButtonPress()}
onNextButtonPress={() => this.handleNextButtonPress()}
onDateSelect={(date) => this.handleDateSelect(date)} />
);
}
}
```

Comment: **Solved**: https://github.com/nikches/react-native-calendar/issues/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the calendar component wrongly.

Try this instead:

`import Calendar from 'react-native-calendar-component';`

Comment: I tried this one but it gives same error. I also tried copying the index.js file from github link renaming it to Calendar.js and importing it as `import Calendar from './Calendar.js'`. Tried this too `import Calendar from './node_modules/react-native-calendar-component';`

Comment: null is not an object (evaluating this.state.date)

Comment: It worked with constructor function, i was trying without the constructor function but it gives error on clicking the calendar component `undefined is not a function(evaluating e.handleDateSelect(t)`)

Comment: Oh, cause I see you have initialized the 'date' state in the constructor function in the snippet. So, I thought the issue is because of you importing the component wrongly (use `import ... from` instead of `require()`). Anyway, glad the problem is solved.